# How can the MEX's APR be requested?

Tags: multiversx

I need to have the MEX's APR from https://maiar.exchange/farms :

[image: mex token apr]

I used https://graph.maiar.exchange/graphql with the following query:
`query{farms{address,farmedTokenPriceUSD, farmingToken{identifier}, apr}}`, but somehow I get a different value from the one from https://maiar.exchange/farms:

```
{
        "address": "erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqpgq5e2m9df5yxxkmr86rusejc979arzayjk2jpsz2q43s",
        "farmedTokenPriceUSD": "1.622850082354300221170064",
        "farmingToken": {
          "identifier": "MEX-455c57"
        },
        "apr": "212.612469918767705563"
      }
```

Comment: Did you get any values for `lockedRewardsAPR` & `unlockedRewardsAPR`?

Comment: I get these values (regarding mex) on https://graph.maiar.exchange/graphql:
``` "data": {"farms": [{ "address": "erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqpgqv4ks4nzn2cw96mm06lt7s2l3xfrsznmp2jpsszdry5","farmingToken": { "identifier": "MEX-455c57"}, "apr": null,
        "lockedRewardsAPR": "1.423083902622313904",
        "unlockedRewardsAPR": "0.118590325218526156"},      {"address":"erd1qqqqqqqqqqqqqpgq5e2m9df5yxxkmr86rusejc979arzayjk2jpsz2q43s","farmingToken": {"identifier": "MEX-455c57"}, "apr": "212.703471673972272078",
        "lockedRewardsAPR": null,
        "unlockedRewardsAPR": null
      }]}```

Comment: That's if I use this query: query{farms{address,farmedTokenPriceUSD, farmingToken{identifier}, apr, lockedRewardsAPR, unlockedRewardsAPR}}

Comment: These 2:
`"lockedRewardsAPR": "1.423083902622313904", "unlockedRewardsAPR": "0.118590325218526156"` look very good, right?

`142% = 142 / 100 = 1.42` and `11% = 11 / 100 = 0.11`